# React native firebase database on value change not triggered

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I have a react native app and using firebase database.

I try to use the `on` or `once` functions to get items from database but I don't know what I am doing wrong because I don't get any data.

This is my code to get data from firebase database:

`firebase.database().ref("messages/").once('value', snapshot => {console.log("snapshot value", snapshot)});`

I try the command from above also with `on` instead of `once` and same result. The `console.log` is never called.

When I am adding messages everything it's ok and the messages appear in the firebase console. For adding messages I am doing like this:

`firebase.database().ref("messages/").push(message);`

For firebase I am using this library: [rnfirebase.io](https://rnfirebase.io)

This are the versions used:
React: 16.6.0-alpha.8af6728
React native: 0.57.4
React native firebase: 5.0.0

Comment: The code you shared looks fine. You might want to add a second callback, to see if there is an error: `firebase.database().ref("messages/").once('value', snapshot => {console.log("snapshot value", snapshot)}, error => { console.error(error); })`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added now the `error`, but nothing changed. No error is displayed in the console.

Comment: The code looks fine to me as well. What versions of React Native, React Native Firebase and the native Firebase SDKs are you using? Could you edit and add these in if possible - thanks

Comment: @Salakar I have added the versions in the post now.

Comment: @DanielDudas great, thanks! So what I imagine is happening here is a bug that recently starting occurring in RN 56 & 57 where RN reloads / live reloads would break listener/reference behaviour. The good news is that there's already a fix; could you install RNFB `v5.1.0-rc3` off of NPM and then follow the upgrade notes for v5.1.0 (still pending release): https://rnfirebase.io/docs/master/release-notes#5.1.0 and let me know if the issue no longer occurs? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase once returns a promise so you have to use then after using value.
The code should be like

```
 firebase.database().ref('tableNameHere').once('value').then(snapshot => {
      if(snapshot.exists()){
         console.log(snapshot.val());
      }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

when using on value the function will invoke on change in value like on CRUD operation

```
 firebase.database().ref('tableNameHere').on('value', snapshot => {
              if(snapshot.exists()){
                 console.log(snapshot.val());
              }
        },(err) => console.log(err))
```